# how to sort and show only top 5 records in simple html table?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-table

I have simple html table with n number of records, i want to sort and show only top records using jquery or javascript. i dont want to use any other plugin.
Thanks in advance

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

tr:nth-child(n+6){
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="mytable">
  <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Ready Duration</th>
      <th>Not-Ready Duration</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
    <td>2019-02-29</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>40</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2019-01-31</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>40</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2019-03-24</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>40</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2019-05-14</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>40</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2019-07-26</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>40</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2019-08-15</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>40</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2019-09-04</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>40</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2019-10-19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>40</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2019-11-24</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>40</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: i want top 5 records based on date

Comment: Your [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74040296/sort-table-and-show-only-top-5-records) was closed because you need to ask only one question - as given in the close reason.  Sorting and limiting rows are very different .  However, you did get numerous usable answers/comments, so you should probably state why they were not good enough.

Answer (score 0):

First use jQuery `sort` to put the newest ones on top. Then use `slice` to show only the first five.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="mytable">
  <thead>
     <tr class="tableHead">
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Ready Duration</th>
      <th>Not-Ready Duration</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
    <td class="date">02-29-2019</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>40</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="date">01-31-2019</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>40</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="date">03-24-2019</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>40</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="date">05-14-2019</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>40</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="date">07-26-2019</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>40</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="date">08-15-2019</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>40</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="date">09-04-2019</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>40</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="date">10-19-2019</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>40</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="date">11-24-2019</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>40</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("tr:not('.tableHead')").sort(function(a, b) {
            let dateA = new Date($(a).find(".date").text());
            let dateB = new Date($(b).find(".date").text());
            return (dateA < dateB) ? 1 : -1;
        }).appendTo($("tbody"));
        $("tr").hide();
        $("tr").slice(0,6).show();
        let dateA = new Date($("tr").find(".date").text());
    });
</script>
```